# Unique id for file names.

Tags: php, function

Hi I have made this code for my project.

```
uniqid().date('ymdhis').rand();
```

How unique is this?

Is it unique enough to prevent any possible collisions? 
Even for big sites with astronomical number of daily file submissions?

Or should I add more functions?
(I don't want to because the output is already quite long.)

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using that for? That will be pretty unique, but say you're just looking for a unique filename, you can use tempnam()

Comment: Maybe [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) function is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what language you are using (i assume it is php)
it is more then enough.

uniqid() is a command that generates a id based on a timestamp, making sure that it won't output a string twice.
so only the `uniqid()` would already suffice

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's PHP. Thank you.